# string builder current size in byte

Tags: .net, stringbuilder

how do i know current byte size of string builder?

Initially it allocates 16 byte. But what is the size of following sb?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("TEST");
```

Comment: Is this a Java or a .NET string builder? Or some other language?

Comment: Oded: Do you know when Java got a `StringBuilder` class?

Answer (score 1):

The *Length* property will be 4 (.NET).

The *length* property will be 4 (Java).

The *capacity* of the .NET `StringBuilder` will still be 16 bytes. See [this](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html) article for details.